# Does a noninteractive login shell execute `~/.profile` or a file whose name is `$BASH_ENV`?

Tags: bash, configuration, profile

From [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

> **Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login**
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as **a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option**, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login
>   shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes
>   commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> **Invoked as an interactive non-login shell**
>
> ...
>
> **Invoked non-interactively**
>
> When Bash is started **non-interactively**, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the
>   filename.
>
> As noted above, if a non-interactive shell is invoked with the --login
>   option, Bash attempts to read and execute commands from the login
>   shell startup files.

Which case does a noninteractive login shell belong to, the first case, or the third case?

The first case "Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login" contains the scenario of "non-interactive shell with the --login option", so I deduce that

- the first case is for login shells regardless of being interactive or noninteractive, and
- the third case is for noninteractive nonlogin shells.

Am I correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, you’re not correct. Bash behaves as documented:

- the first section applies to interactive login shells, and to non-interactive shells started with the `--login` flag;
- the third section applies to non-interactive shells, including non-interactive login shells *not* started with the `--login` flag.

A shell can be a login shell without the `--login` flag. If you look at `/proc/$$/cmdline` from a Bash shell started by SSH on a Linux system, you’ll see it was started as `-bash` — the leading hyphen is the usual way of starting a login shell, and isn’t covered by the first section if it ends up being non-interactive. However if one wanted a non-interactive login shell for whatever reason, one would typically use `--login` to get it.

Comment: Thanks. What kinds of "non-interactive shells" does the third section refer to? Are "non-interactive shells started with the --login flag" still noninteractive shells? Are "non-interactive shells started with the --login flag" login shells?

Comment: See the description of the non-interactive shell in your quote: “to run a shell script, for example”. A non-interactive shell is non-interactive, yes, and a shell started with `--login` is a login shell, yes. I gave you all the tools you need to verify this for yourself, I encourage you to use them...

Comment: Thanks. So "non-interactive shells started with the --login flag" are noninteractive login shells. Does the third section apply to all non-interactive login shells except those which are "non-interactive shells started with the --login flag"?

Comment: This is getting seriously theoretical, there isn’t a practical, common way of starting a non-interactive *login* shell except by using the `--login` option.

Comment: Sorry that this goes into theoretical from your pespective. Is it correct that "run a shell script" creates a  noninteractive nonlogin shell? What are non-interactive login shells which are not "non-interactive shells started with the --login flag"?  If "there isn’t a practical, common way of starting a non-interactive login shell except by using the --login option", then can I say that all non-interactive login shells are started with the --login flag?

Comment: `-bash` is not a command found in bash. How shall I run `-bash`?

Comment: Actually there _is_ a practical way: `exec -a -bash bash -c 'shopt login_shell ; echo $-'`

Comment: @JdeBP for some value of “practical”...

Comment: @Tim yes, shell scripts use non-interactive, non-login shells by default. No, you can’t say that all non-interactive login shells are started with the `--login` flag, because there are other ways of starting them.

Comment: Thanks. `-bash` is not a command found in bash, when I type it in a bash shell. How shall I run `-bash`?

Comment: @JdeBP Could you explain a little of what `exec -a -bash bash -c 'shopt login_shell ; echo $-' ` does, and why is it a noninteractive login shell?